# The popup explanation for tag scores is confusing when you have only posted questions but not answers

Tags: feature-request, information-display, tag-score

In the tag section of a user profile, each tag has a number on its right and a number on its left. The number on the left represents the score of answers in that tag (i.e. total upvotes on answers in that tag minus total downvotes on answers in that tag), and the number on the right represents the total number of posts in that tag (i.e. total number of questions plus total number of answers. The explanation that pops up when you hover the mouse over it is generally consistent with this.

However, in a situation where a user has only posted questions, the popup explanation leads to some confusion, as can be seen in this example:

[image: Screenshot showing example where there is no answer score]

Here the number on the left is zero because I have not posted any answers, and therefore I have no answer score. The popup explanation doesn't mention answers at all, though. It merely tells me that I have asked two questions with a total score of seven. This is confusing on two counts. First, the popup explanation, which presumably exists to explain what the numbers mean, tells me nothing about what the zero means. Second, the popup explanation tells me that I have a score of seven, which doesn't seem to have anything to do with the original numbers. The only thing here that is understandable is that I have asked two questions.

Compare this to an example where there are both questions and answers:

[image: Screenshot showing example where there is an answer score]

Here the number on the left matches precisely with what the popup explanation says my answer score is, and the number on the right matches precisely with what the popup explanation gives as my total of questions plus answers. It is thus clear, that the original numbers represent only answer score and total posts, and the information about question score in the popup explanation is *additional*.

To prevent this confusion in the case where there are no answers, I would suggest that the popup explanation should explicitly say that there are no answers, instead of only discussing questions. It should say something like:

> Asked 2 non-wiki questions with a total score of 7. Gave 0 non-wiki answers with a total score of 0.

This would exactly parallel what it supplies when there *are* answers, and it is now clear what the original zero represents.

Answer (score 5):

Having consistent user prompts is important for reducing confusion. I think your idea should be extended to other cases where parts of the prompt disappear on no posts in the tag (the screenshots below show already modified titles).

Some questions without answers:

[image: preview: some questions, no answers]

Some answers without questions:

[image: preview: some answers, no questions]

Give it 6 to 8 weeks to be done. In the meantime, here is a simple snippet for fixing this for you (the snippet omits the "with a total score of 0" part because one cannot give zero answers with a total score *other* than zero).

TypeScript source:

```ts
((_w, d) => {
    const answerVotes = [
        ...d.querySelectorAll<HTMLDivElement>(".answer-votes"),
    ];
    answerVotes.forEach((av) => {
        const { title, textContent } = av;

        const prepend = title.includes("question")
            ? ""
            : "Asked 0 non-wiki questions.";

        const append = title.includes("answer")
            ? ""
            : "Gave 0 non-wiki answers.";

        av.title = title.trim()
            ? `${prepend} ${title} ${append}`
            : `${prepend} ${append}`;
    });
})(window, document);
```

Compiled, minified, and uglified version:

```js
var __read=this&&this.__read||function(r,e){var t="function"==typeof Symbol&&r[Symbol.iterator];if(!t)return r;var n,o,i=t.call(r),a=[];try{for(;(void 0===e||0<e--)&&!(n=i.next()).done;)a.push(n.value)}catch(r){o={error:r}}finally{try{n&&!n.done&&(t=i.return)&&t.call(i)}finally{if(o)throw o.error}}return a},__spread=this&&this.__spread||function(){for(var r=[],e=0;e<arguments.length;e++)r=r.concat(__read(arguments[e]));return r};!function(r){__spread(r.querySelectorAll(".answer-votes")).forEach(function(r){var e=r.title,t=(r.textContent,e.includes("question")?"":"Asked 0 non-wiki questions."),n=e.includes("answer")?"":"Gave 0 non-wiki answers.";r.title=e.trim()?t+" "+e+" "+n:t+" "+n})}((window,document));
```